# Scrapy, scrape from drop down menu

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the names of some towns/cities from a drop down menu.

The html looks like:

> option value="/salaries/**THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT**"
>   data-tn-link
>   data-tn-element="loc_city[]">        Acton

I have tried this:

```
def parse_cities(self, response):
        for city in response.xpath('//select[@id="cmp-salary-loc-select"]/option/text()').extract():
            print(scrapy.Request(response.urljoin("/"+city)))
```

With no luck.

I know that this

`response.xpath('//select[@id="cmp-salary-loc-select"]/option').extract()`

Returns all the html I need, But just can't seem to get the values?

Any pointers would be appreciated. I haven't posted the link as I do want to try figure this one out rather than someone do it for me! But will add in if you guys think it would help?

Comment: You have a misprint in `def parse_cities(self, respone):` change to `response`. Also, why do you try to print scrapy request?

Comment: thanks. I was printing just to try test it out. But I know it's the response.xpath part that I need to get right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def parse_cities(self, response):
  for city in response.xpath('//select[@id="cmp-salary-loc-select"]/option/@value').extract():
     yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin("/"+city), callback=some_method)
```